# Structuring siblings relation on same model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `student` model. I want to add siblings from existing students table on user profile page. I am selecting sibling from a dropdown. Also I want to add the parents of old student(sibling) to the new student(sibling). For student parent I have many-to-many relationship and I am saving `student_id` and `parent_id` in pivot table

How can I structure and add this sibling part?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to represent this family relations (parents , children , siblings) is to put **a nullable parent_id** in students table,

so when this **parent_id** is null this mean that the object is a main parent otherwise it's just a child.
After that you can define some relations :

```
 public function children()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(self::class, "parent_id");
 }

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, "parent_id");
}
```

and for the siblings , I don't know if there is a way to write a relation , but you can return the siblings like so :

```
$siblings = Student::where("parent_id", $this->parent_id)->get();
```

Comment: I have different model for parents, and same model for students and siblings